# SharePoint caching and how to ignore it

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-enterprise, caching, web-services

I am new to SharePoint so I may be asking a very simple question.

We have a webservice in java which accepts a username and password and using these crendentials it hits SharePoint (using ntlm windows authentication) List Service.

When we enter the wrong credentials for the first time, it gives authentication exception and its fine.

Next we provided the right credentials and it provided the list, its fine again.

After this, I entered the wrong credentials and SharePoint responded with the list rather than exception. This time I felt its not fine.

I think SharePoint stores the credentials somewhere and does not check it again.

I felt this because when I hit the SharePoint site from browser it demanded for credentials after that I deleted all the history of browser, and opened a new browser, it does not ask for credentials.

Please suggest what can I do.

Is there some way to avoid this caching or some sort of logout code it available?

Comment: Did you delete all cookies when you deleted browser history in your test? I think the problem could be your web service framework in Java keeping the session alive rather than the SharePoint web service.

Comment: I deleted everyhing from the browser cookies password history everything..

Comment: Which authentication is used by your SharePoint application?

Comment: @Amit Kumawat Window authentication(NTLM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zone settings in IE might be playing some kind of part. The URL needs to be in 'Intranet' and if you need to force SharePoint to prompt then you could just adjust the zone settings to prompt each time you access the site?

Also Ctrl+F5 on IE will supposedly reload the page completley.